# XSLT regex doesn't match even when in online regex tests match correctly

Tags: regex, xslt, xslt-2.0, pcre

Given example path C:\example\innerExample\file.txt, I want to extract filename with extension using this regex, you can [see it here](https://regex101.com/r/24uDT5/2).

```
<xsl:analyze-string select="$filePath" regex="$regexPattern" flags="mis">
  <xsl:matching-substring>
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(regex-group(2), regex-group(3))"/>
  </xsl:matching-substring>
</xsl:analyze-string>
```

This is my xslt code, is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Please post a reproducible example (something we can test without having to assemble it from bits and pieces) - see: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Without going into your attempt (which I cannot reproduce), I believe you can extract the  filename with extension simply by using:

```
<xsl:value-of select="tokenize($filepath, '\\')[last()]"/>
```

---

**Demo**: http://xsltransform.hikmatu.com/6qVRKvN

Comment: It worked for windows path, but considering I can provide dynamic regexPattern from external source, how can I apply to my $filePath? Sorry for not giving you enough details, but I'm really, really new in XSLT, so I have no clue what I'm doing and how to do it properly.

Comment: The second argument to the `tokenize()` function is actually a regex pattern (and you can add a third argument for flags). For anything more, please edit your question as requested.

Comment: And how can I pick particular groups from this regexp?

Comment: @kkot You can't. But you can add alternative delimiters.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown us a complete but minimal examples with the proper values but with the correction of not escaping the `/` in the square brackets I think your pattern works with XSLT/XPath 2 and later:

Input

```
<root>
    <data>C:\example\innerExample\file.txt</data>
</root>
```

is at https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/jyRYYhM transformed with

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:param name="regexPattern" as="xs:string">^(.*)[/|\\](.*)(\..*)</xsl:param>

  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
      <xsl:copy>
          <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="{$regexPattern}" flags="mis">
              <xsl:matching-substring>
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(regex-group(2), regex-group(3))"/>
              </xsl:matching-substring>
          </xsl:analyze-string>
      </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

into

```
<root>
    <data>file.txt</data>
</root>
```

(I have used XSLT 3 there but I think there has been no change between XSLT 2 and 3 in terms of `xsl:analyze-string`).

Comment: ... and changing `regex="$regexPattern"` to `regex="{$regexPattern}"`.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, that's true, somehow I made that change automatically when creating the example but forgot to mention it. @kkot. the `regex` attribute needs to use attribute value template syntax to use the value of a parameter or variable.